# write a variable into an xml file using php

Tags: php, xml, variables

Hey there i'm trying to generate an XML file with php variables.
but echo or print don't seem to work watch my snippet below.
How could i achieve what i'm trying todo?

```
  $xml = new DOMDocument();
 $root = $xml->createElement('package');
 $root = $xml->appendChild($root);
  $title = $xml->createElement('id' , echo $_GET['bundleid']);
   $title = $root->appendChild($title);
```

Comment: Are you building the XML from a posted form? use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET` And don't need to echo the variable

Comment: @luenib How does POST or GET make a difference?

Comment: Don't `echo` when assigning. Are you trying to output the full XML?

Answer (score 0):

As luenib pointed out, you generally don't put "echo" before variables that you pass to  functions as arguments. Below is a simple example of outputting XML to browser or writing to file.

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$root = $xml->createElement('package');
$root = $xml->appendChild($root);
$title = $xml->createElement('id' , $_GET['bundleid']); // no "echo" before variable
//$title = $xml->createElement('id' , $_POST['bundleid']);
//$title = $xml->createElement('id' , $bundleid);
//$title = $xml->createElement('id' , 'bundleid');
$title = $root->appendChild($title);
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml_string = $xml->saveXML();

// Store XML to file.
file_put_contents('path/myXmlFile.xml',$xml_string);

// Output XML to browser.
//header("Content-type: text/xml");
//echo $xml_string;
```